# The C# equivalent

Tags: c#

I am trying to close the program :HHTCntrl.exe as if the user clicked exit on that program. I have the following Borland C++ code. What is the C# equivalent?

```
FILE *sf;
AnsiString ClosePollControl = AnsiString("HHT")+cbHHTNo->Text+AnsiString(".cls");
sf = fopen(ClosePollControl.c_str(),"w");
fclose(sf);
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to *achieve*? Rather than give the C++ code, tell us what the aim is and we're more likely to be able to help you.

Comment: am trying to close the program :HHTCntrl.exe as if the user clicked exit on that program

Comment: How does that fit together with your code? Your code looks like you open some file for writing. Closing is usually done by sending `WM_CLOSE`

Comment: I think it is pretty clear what he wants to achieve. No one would rightly assume that he actually wants an AnsiString in C#. He just wants the syntactical equivalent. Just like if he were to ask convert this VB.NET code to C#.

Comment: @Code Monkey: That's the point I don't get. And does `File.Close` even exist? Opening/Closing a file is completely unrelated to closing a program. Closing a program like the user clicked exit usually involves sending it windows messages directly or indirectly.

Comment: @Code: Yes, I agree. I took it as the OP wanted to see his code's equivalent in C#. Now I don't know what to believe.

Answer (score 2):

You're opening the file for writing. Assuming that `cbHHTNo` is the `string` containing file name, in C# it will go like that:

```
var path = "HHT" + cbHHTNo + ".cls";
using (var file = File.OpenWrite(path))
{
    // do sth with the open file stream here
}
```

Comment: sorry for the confusion people, im still learning borland c++ and c# and am trying to understand this code that was given to me

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is actually pretty simple.

There isn't a concept of an `AnsiString` in C# so you have to use a `string`.

```
string ClosePollControl = "HHT" + cbHHTNo->Text + ".cls";
// Open the stream and write to it.
using (FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite(ClosePollControl)) 
{

}
```

This assumes you have some user level control, `cbHHTNo`, that you are getting the `Text` (e.g. `string`).

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to shutdown the process then use System.Diagnostics.Process class. For example,

```
Process process = Process.GetProcessesByName("HHTCntrl.exe").FirstOrDefault();

if (process != null)
{
     process.Kill(); // to immediatelly kill the process or use process.CloseMainWindow() to gracefully "kill" the process
}
```

If you want to close an active form use Close() method.